# Java - Table display error on first row when there is no result found

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jtable

I have hard time to figure this out... I want display error on first row when there is no result found for example on this **[SITE](http://dota2prices.com/sets/)** there is search bar when I type random words that none on the table... the table will display error and remain the header name...

this is my code so far...

```
    String tempSearchValue = searchStudent.getText().trim();
    boolean empty = true;
    sql = "SELECT student_id as 'Student ID',"
            + "concat(lastname, '  ,  ', firstname, ' ', middlename) as 'Name'"
            + "FROM user "
            + "WHERE CAST(student_id as CHAR) LIKE '%" + tempSearchValue + "%'";
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
            empty = false;
        }
        if(empty) {

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: You had nothing in the `if(empty) {` section, that's probably why

Comment: yeah i don't know how to that and what I put on there `String error = "No matching records found";`
                and then this `table.setModel(error);`

Comment: The site you linked to is obviously using AJAX. And if you were actually building the HTML rather than using   table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)) it would be obvious.

Comment: Just create a table model with a single cell with that text. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data

Comment: yeah what is that code to insert?

Comment: can you just tell me cause this is not working `table.setModel("No matching records found");`